# Has anyone else seen this IE6.0 Display problem?

Tags: internet-explorer-6, rendering

Has anyone seen this type of IE display problem?

[Example http://xs133.xs.to/xs133/08465/ie_problem910.jpg.xs.jpg](http://xs133.xs.to/xs133/08465/ie_problem910.jpg.xs.jpg)

Note that it is doing some sort of word-wrap/duplication when it renders.

The code for the brown box and the text that should be in it is:

```
<div class='span-23'>
    <div class='span-7'>
        <div class='info_box' style='height: 30px; padding-top: 10px'>
            <div class='span-4'><b>Vehicle Full Term Premium:</b></div>
            <div class='span-2' id='veh_ft_prem' style='text-align: right;'></div>
            <div class='span-4'><b>Vehicle Written Premium:</b></div>
            <div class='span-2' id='veh_writ_prem' style='text-align: right;'></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm using BlueprintCSS and the info_box CSS class is:

```
.info_box {
background: #fbe6a0;
color: #222222;
border-color: #222222;
padding:.8em;
padding-right: 0;
margin-bottom:1em;
border:2px solid #222222;}
```

Comment: Looks right to me.  I think you didn't include something in your question.  Perhaps a pic of what you THINK it should look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bunch of fiddling, it turns out that if you have a hidden object ABOVE the box I showed, that is the cause of the problem.

Sorry I didn't give you more information, but at the time, it did seem exactly as Patrick said and there shouldn't have been a IE render bug.

I hope that helps someone else out there!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.. sorry but I didn't see your problem.. even in IE6.

Well, there are several websites that are very good in CSS issues and etc. 
Try http://www.positioniseverything.net is a very good one =D

Sorry if I couldn't help..

Answer (score 0):

Nothing there looks like it even **could** cause that under the strangest of IE render bugs.